# Switch active view between two Revit Documents

Tags: c#, api, document, revit

I have a doc that is already opened in revit. A C# addin is activated and a form(modal?) is opened. A button event is then implemented to open a doc to transfer some mass elements from that file and document to the already opened document.

```
//the rvt file containing the mass elements opening code.
Document doc = app.OpenDocumentFile(UserRVTFilePath);
```

I then would like to switch the active document back to the first opened document. Is there a Revit API method that exists to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the    UIApplication.OpenAndActivateDocument(string revitPath)     method?

```
public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData cmdData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
{
    UIDocument uiDoc = cmdData.Application.OpenAndActivateDocument(@"c:\project.rvt");
    // do stuff with uiDoc

    return Result.Succeeded;
}
```

Also you can get a reference to current Active UIDocument using:     UIApplication.ActiveUIDocument